# Python 3.8 and Scrapy 2.4.1 "No module named <name of my project>

Tags: python, module, scrapy, relative-path, absolute-path

I met a problem I'm not able to jump through. I use scrapy (2.4.1), python3.8.6 and Pycharm. My project structure is like that:

- project_folder

  - scrapy_project

    - spiders

      - **init**.py
      - my_spider.py
  - **init**.py
  - items.py
  - middlewares.py
  - pipeline.py
  - run.py
  - settings.py

when I run my spider from Pycharm using Run - it works.
when I run my spider using:
scrapy crawl <spider_name> - it works.

But when I do this from terminal using:

```
               python3 <path_to_the_script/my_spider.py
```

a have error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_project'.**

```
       in my_spider.py I used from scrapy_project.items import <Class_name>Item ]
```

I used  print(sys.path) tho check what is in my PYTHONATHS and I have there path to my directory:

```
          /Users/user/Desktop/project_folder/scrapy_project'
```

I have no idea what to do. I want to start my spider from the schedule in Pythonanywhere but when I run my script over there I have got the same error.

Doy You Guys have got any idea where the problem is?

I will be thankful for every tip.

Comment: What’s the output of `pwd`? If you are not at `project_folder`, you are in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CrawlerProcess to run as a regular Python script.

[Scrapy Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)